# how to return and display on template the username and group in django

Tags: django, templates, authentication

i have a login system using django i want to be able to display the **logged in user** and **the group** that belong to it in the base template that include the navigation bar.

until now i am  able to return the username and the group  and printed out in the console. and its showing the username in the template but **without the group**

## views.py

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['lognName']
        password = request.POST['lognCode']
        user = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            print("user is authenticated", {username})
        else:
            print("user is NOT authenticated", {username})
        currentU = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
        currentID = currentU.id
        print('current user is : ',currentID)
        groupName=User.objects.all().get(pk=currentID).groups.get().name
        print('set done ')
        print('the Groups Name {0}'.format(groupName))
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.info(request,f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("create")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"invalid username or password")
            print("invalid username or password")

    return render(request,'login.html')
```

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <link rel= "icon" type= "image/png" href="{% static 'img/logo_title/icon-AddressBar.png'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/search.css'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/style.css'%}">
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- <div class="Horizontal-scale"> -->
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>


  <div id="container" class="Horizontal-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">{{ user }} || {{ groupName }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}" id="logMeOut">logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">search</a></li>
            <li><a href="{%  url 'list'  %}">list members</a></li>
            <li><a href="{%  url 'create'  %}">mainpage</a></li>
             </th>
    </ul>

</script>
</body>

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

</html>
```

Comment: You have to send the groupName to the template, you can do it like this: `return render(request,'login.html', {'user': user, 'groupName': groupName})` and then access these vars using `{{user}}` or `{{groupName`}} from template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see form [official documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model), Django's built-in `User` model has ManyToMany relation with `Group` model. You can access user groups by `user.groups` but as there may be more than one group that a user is assigned to, you will need a `for` loop type of expression to show it.

```html
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ group.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it display this error : 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add ```all```, can you try it again?

Comment: thank you for your answer this was correct .

i have another question if you can help me with  about the dynamic navigation bar

Comment: Please ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
{{user.groups.all.0.name}}
```